# Alternative to XPath id() in .NET

Tags: .net, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML document:

```
<text xmlns:its="http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its" >
 <its:rules version="2.0">
  <its:termRule selector="//term" term="yes" termInfoPointer="id(@def)"/>
 </its:rules>
 <p>We may define <term def="TDPV">discoursal point of view</term>
 as <gloss xml:id="TDPV">the relationship, expressed through discourse
  structure, between the implied author or some other addresser,
  and the fiction.</gloss>
 </p>
</text>
```

`termInfoPointer` is an XPath expression which points to the `<gloss xml:id="TDPV">` element.

I use LINQ-to-XML to select it.

```
XElement term = ...;
object value = term.XPathEvaluate("id(@def)");
```

I get the following exception: `System.NotSupportedException: This XPathNavigator does not support IDs.`

I couldn't find a solution to this problem so I tried to replace `id()` with other expressions:

```
//*[@xml:id='TDPV'] // works, but I need to use @def

//*[@xml:id=@def]
//*[@xml:id=@def/text()]
//*[@xml:id=self::node()/@def/text()]
```

but none of these works.

Is there a way to implement `id()` or replace it with another expression?

I'd prefer a solution/workaround that doesn't involve replacing `id()` with another expression because this expression could be something complex like `id(@def) | id(//*[@attr="(id(@abc()))))))"])`.

Comment: The `id()` function only works correctly if the source XML document has a DTD with elements defined as ID -- without such a DTD don't expect the `id()` function to be evaluated as wanted -- in any compliant XPath implementation. In case this prerequisite is satisfied, then you can try to convert the XDocument to an ordinary XMLDocument (or XpathNavigator) and use the `SelectNodes()` (or `Evaluate()`) method(s).

Comment: Here's a workaround that works in Java: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-multilingualweb-lt-tests/2013Jan/0064.html

Comment: mak, the referred java workaround doesn't work in your case. You need to write an evaluation method that accepts a string, representing an XPath expression and evaluates it. You'll use the result produced by this method to construct the final XPath expression that will select the element(s) whose `id` attributes have that value.

Comment: One way would be to replace all occurences of "id(" with "myId(". Also, implement an `myId()` extension function, using the XsltContext class (see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext.resolvefunction.aspx)

Comment: If someone had this expression `//*[@attr="id(..)"]` it'd get replaced with `//*[@attr="myId(..)"]`. I must admit this is what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Yes, this is the general solution I recommended in my last comment.If you code the `myId()` function following the rules of the `XsltContext` class, then you'll just use XPath.Evaluate() on the new expression in which `id()` is replaced by `myId()`.

Comment: But it's an ugly hack which can have unintended consequences (like I showed in my last comment). I'll wait till the end before awarding the bounty.

Comment: No, no unintended consequences -- if the code for the `myId()` function is written correctly.

Comment: How can I replace "id(" with "myId(" with the `XsltContext` class, like you advised? Currently I'm using a simple regular expression to replace all occurrences of "id(" with "myId(" in the expression string but that affects unrelated expressions like `//[@attr="id(..)"]`

Comment: I didn't say anywhere to use XsltContext for the replacement -- the replacement must be done with C# and its RegEx support -- so that every occurence if "id(" would be replaced with "myId(". Then you evaluate the new string (as XPath expression) and here is where your `myId()` function would be resolved and called.

Comment: Not every occurrence of "id(" is a reference to the `id()` function, that's the problem.

Comment: mak, Why? You only need a simple RegEx to correctly find and replace these.

Comment: I'm not smart enough to come up with one.

Comment: mak, you need something like: "[^a-zA-z0-9]*(id\()" -- and replace the captured strings with "myId("

Comment: Your simple regex will also replace "id("s which are in quotes.

Comment: mak, Sure, but even this is a good first step. I wrote this in a second -- more elaborate Regexes are possible. If you know that a given Regex isn't perfect, but will do the job in 99.99% of the time, just use it.

Answer (score 5):

**If the `def` attribute is guaranteed to appear only once in the XMLdocument, use:**

```
//*[@xml:id = //@def]
```

If there might be different `def` attributes, then you need to provide an XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted `def` attribute in your case:

```
//*[@xml:id = someExpressionSelectingTheWantedDefAttribute]
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//*[@xml:id = //@def]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<text xmlns:its="http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its" >
 <its:rules version="2.0">
  <its:termRule selector="//term" term="yes" termInfoPointer="id(@def)"/>
 </its:rules>
 <p>We may define <term def="TDPV">discoursal point of view</term>
 as <gloss xml:id="TDPV">the relationship, expressed through discourse
  structure, between the implied author or some other addresser,
  and the fiction.</gloss>
 </p>
</text>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation (the selected element) is copied to the output**:

```
<gloss xmlns:its="http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its" xml:id="TDPV">the relationship, expressed through discourse
  structure, between the implied author or some other addresser,
  and the fiction.</gloss>
```

Comment: Thanks for the XSLT-based verification example, I didn't know about that. I've no idea how many times `def` can appear or even if it's an attribute. I think I could have `<term><id>TDPV</id>...</term>` with an expression `id(./id/text())`. I was hoping there's an XPath function that I didn't know of that evaluates an expression and returns a value that I could use in `//*[@xml:id=evaluate(@def)]`

Comment: @mak, If you are asking for *dynamic evaluation*, this isn't possible even in XPath 3.0 (possible in XSLT 4.0 with the new instruction `<xsl:evaluate>`). But it seems to me that you don't need dynamic evaluation here -- just manually specify the expression that brings the value to be compared.